# heightmap from textures and hight poly mesh to apply to low polly mesh?

Tags: rendering, mesh, game-engine

i want the height map from the textures but I also want the heightmap from the high poly mesh so I can apply it to a low poly mesh. I want both in one heightmap but I don't know how to. please help

Comment: If I understand what you want correctly, you could [bake a normal map](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Bake) based on the difference between the low-poly mesh and the high-poly one, and then use it in combination with your other hightmap.

Comment: @gandalf3 I think he want's a displacement map. He has a high-poly mesh with a displacement map and wants to bake the high-poly+displacement to a low-poly mesh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basics:

- Apply your texture as a normal map to your highpoly mesh.
- Unwrap the lowpoly mesh and add an image to it (to bake to).
- Select the highpoly, add the lowpoly to the selection (important to do this last). Bake normals.

With images:

- Highpoly + lowpoly meshes

[image: highpoly+lowpoly]

- Test render of highpoly + texture

[image: rendered highpoly (with texture as normal)]

- a voronoi texture applied as normal map

[image: my normal texture]

- Bake setup and result.

[image: baked texture]

Answer (score 1):

And also, to add to all of that.

(i) You can use the technique above to bake a height map as well.

(ii) You can also heavily subdivide a mesh using the *multires modifier* and then apply the texture to a *displace modifier*.  This will help for baking height maps as well as normal maps.

You will have to twiddle those *bias* and *distance* settings for baking *selected to active*.  They are very difficult to configure on curved surfaces.

EDIT: I almost forgot about the following setup.  It's for baking a height map using Cycles.  It was posted on BlenderArtists.org a while back.  Currently it only works for planer projection, not curved meshes, but when the situation is appropriate, it generates flawless height maps.

http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?273033-Sculpting-with-UVs-and-displacements/

[image]

Comment: okay. so this worked but it can only be an "open mesh" (I think that's the term used) so like. a cube wont work but a plane will. could you show me how to do this on a "closed mesh" please?

Comment: Interesting, I just showed up here because I wanted to explain this to someone else and there is fairly new comment from you that I was not notified of.  Good timing.  I'll get back to you on this.

Comment: There is no Cycles baking of true displacement yet for curved 3D objects, not officially.  I've been doing a black and white bake with no Margin overdraw to accomplish this.  Save out this mask and load it in again and apply it to a plane.  Now setup an orthographic camera so that it perfectly captures only this plane.  Now build geometry using the UV islands shown on the plane as a guide and finish this with a camera render as shown above.  Now apply this rendered depth map to your mesh as a Displace texture using the UV setting in the modifier.

Comment: See my question here for further details on how to do this.  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14074/is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-meshs-uvs-into-a-seond-mesh-using-a-script