# Transferring changes from UV to a mesh

Tags: uv

For the sake of example let's say I have a subdivided plane mesh and then I start to edit its UV map by changing vertices positions etc in the UV editor. Is there a way to apply those changes to the mesh geometry itself?
 As in I have a texture and I have changed the vertices positions accordingly so that it all fits perfectly - but I did so in the UV editor and now I want the actual mesh geometry to reproduce those changes and those vertices positions as well (since the mesh is just a plane), is there a way to do so?

Comment: Please add a printscreen /screenshots to your question, so everyone else is able to visualize your challenge too

Comment: [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14074/is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-meshs-uvs-into-a-second-mesh-using-a-script) to a previous BSE question might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it manually, but it is tedious:

- change the plane's 3D origin to the bottom right of the plane, so that all of the planes local coordinates are equal or above 0, like your UV coordinates[image: cursor]
  [image: origin]
- now click on each vertex of the plane and in the top part of the Proprieties panel press "Local", change Y to 0 then change X and Z to your UV coordinates
  [image]
- to know which vertex in UV space belongs to which vertex in 3D space , click
  "Keep UV and edit mode mesh selection in sync"
  [image]