# There is a way to reverse-unrap in Python?

Tags: python, uv

I am trying reverse-unfold the mesh in 3D view comforming with the UV map,
But I couldn't even get to acess the UVs.
Is there a way to do that?

[image]

Comment: See the textools addon: https://blenderartists.org/t/textools-for-blender/700811 .  Might still be only in the dev / beta version.

Comment: Duplcate from. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14074/is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-meshs-uvs-into-a-second-mesh-using-a-script