# How to unwrap an object into sheet in the 3d view?

Tags: modeling

I want to make animation about how a sheetmetal part is made. I don't need help with the animation but I don't know how to unwrap it (or un-origami it, I hope you understand). Basically it is like uv unwrapping the 3d model but doing it in the 3d viewport.

I don't need advice about the animation part. Just how to unwrap the 3d model into a plane without having to do it manually vertex and face at a time individually. I know there will be little bit of distortion with complex models but the model I have is something simple like a cylinder with different radius ends, like this for example:

[image: sample image of beveled cylinder]

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14076/35559)

Comment: Tbh, I'm not sure what the problem is. Go into edit mode, press U and choose an unwrap option. Automatic unwrap would be Smart UV Project. Toy with the options, see if it's nice enough.

Comment: Robin Betts, that looks perfect!

Comment: Actually the script seems to error out a ton. It worked for a basic cube but if I add an unsymmetric loop cut the script already breaks.